# Show or hide notebook page in Odoo?

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, forms, odoo-13

Is there any way to show/hide page in the odoo form when button is clicked ?

There is a page in my contact form I want to hide or show based on button click.

I don't want to use attribute method or any xpath.

Just click button page show up and click that button again it will hide.

Does JS can be written in Odoo form for this process?

Answer (score 1):

It's doable but I don't think it's a good approach, you can make a click event that will trigger toggle to hide/show the notebook. But in your case, I would recommend that you do it through security if you want to show/hide the notebook for specific users.

Comment: It may not be a good approach but I do need to hide the notebook page because there I have used iframe element and I want to toggle the display based on that button action.